# How to illustrate saccades with the help of tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, typography

While reading our eyes moves in so-called saccades which are "jumps" between "syllables" (actually it is a jump from word presence to word presence (or word image to wordimage -- sorry don't know the right term). I found a sketch which describes that (version B):

[image]syllable

My question is: how to rebuild the saccades on own texts with tikz? Is there a way to jump automatically from word presence to word presence or do I have to set nodes in the text manually?
Background: I have the chance to give a presentation and wanna illustrate why too long lines aren't good to read (typical A4-paper settings). I wanna also show why shorter lines like in Tufte classes are convenient to read ("But isn't that a waste of paper?" "No. It's a waste of paper if no-one wanna read your paper work, just because your lines are too long!")

Comment: I'm not sure what precisely you mean by "automatically". Do you want LaTeX/TikZ to automatically break flowing text into saccades _and_ draw/annotate the lines, or do you want to enter text somehow pre-split into saccades (with some strategy for delimiting them) and have the drawing/annotation done automatically?

Comment: @PaulGessler: your second suggestion is what i mean by "automatically". But i would really be happy enough with a "manual" solution. It is not, that i have to give presentations about this toppic very often; so a manual solution would also be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is (at least) one problem with this solution: The inter-saccade arrow is insufficient.  EDITED to greatly improve efficiency by disabling mathstyle preservation feature of `scalerel` package.  While a great feature usually, if one nests 3 `scalerel` calls as is done here in `\saccade`, there are 4^3 mathchoice boxes constructed for each invocation.

The macros are

`\saccade{text}` to provide saccade arc over text

`\Comment[alignment]{comment text}{\saccade-group}` to provide comment above saccades

`\Ssaccade{starting text}` to start the saccade

`\Esaccade{ending text}` to end the saccade

`\labelsaccade[lines of depth]{label}` provides left side label, allocates vertical underdepth

`\nosaccade{text}` to avoid the saccade arc

`\noSsaccade{text}` to avoid the saccade arc at beginning of text line

`\dashsaccade{text}` (unfortunately, the dash width will change with text length).

The macro  `\saccade` actually has an optional argument which the user can ignore, but is employed by `\Ssaccade` and `\Esaccade`.

If the horizontal alignment of the saccade is not correct, the OP can let me know and I can adjust.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,trimclip,xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\Frown{\addstackgap[.2pt]{$\mkern-.9mu\frown\mkern-.7mu$}}
\newcommand\saccade[2][\Frown]{\let\mathchoice\relax%
  \stackon[\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+1pt\relax]{\bfseries#2}{%
    \stretchto{%
      \scaleto{%
        \scalerel*[\widthof{\bfseries#2}]{#1}%
                  {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%
      }{\textheight}%
    }{2.5ex}%
  }\ignorespaces%
}
\newcommand\Ssaccade[1]{\saccade[\clipbox{4pt 0pt .1pt 0pt}{\Frown}]{\hspace{9ex}#1}}
\newcommand\Esaccade[1]{\saccade[\clipbox{.1pt 0pt 4pt 0pt}{\Frown}]{#1\hspace{9ex}}}
\newcommand\Comment[3][c]{\renewcommand\stackalignment{#1}%
  \stackon[2\baselineskip]{#3}{\small\itshape\Longstack[l]{#2}}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\labelsaccade[2][2]{\rule[-#1\baselineskip]{0pt}{1pt}%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\Large #2\hspace{1cm}}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\crossrule[2]{\hspace{#1}\rule[.5pt]{#2}{1pt}}
\def\dashFrown{\vphantom{\Frown}\setbox0=\hbox{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{b}{}{\textcolor{white}{\rotatebox{150}{\crossrule{1.4ex}{.4ex}}}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{b}{}{\textcolor{white}{\rotatebox{30}{\crossrule{1.3ex}{.4ex}}}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{b}{-1pt}{\textcolor{white}{\rotatebox{90}{\crossrule{1ex}{.3ex}}}}{%
    \Frown%
}}}}\smash{\box0}}
\newcommand\nosaccade[1]{\textbf{#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\noSsaccade[1]{\hspace{9ex}\textbf{#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\dashsaccade[1]{\saccade[\dashFrown]{#1}}
%%% THE FOLLOWING DISABLES MATH-MODE PRESERVATION OF scalerel, WHICH MAKES
%%% NESTED scalerel MACROS MUCH MORE EFFICIENT BY ELIMINATING NESTED \mathchoice
\makeatletter
  \edef\m@switch{T}\LMex=1ex\relax\LMpt=1pt\relax%
  \renewcommand\ThisStyle[1]{\ifmmode\def\@mmode{T}#1\else\def\@mmode{F}#1\fi}
\makeatother
%%%
\begin{document}
\labelsaccade{A}
\Comment[l]{Entry\\saccade}{\Ssaccade{Ji}}
\Comment{Minisaccades (without estim.)}
{\saccade{m dr}\saccade{es-s}\saccade{eX w}\saccade{ell y}\saccade{es-t}\saccade{er-d}}
\Comment[r]{Exit\\saccade}{\Esaccade{ay}}

\labelsaccade{B}
\Comment[l]{Entry\\saccade}{\Ssaccade{Ji}}
\Comment{Minisaccades (with correct estim.)}
{\saccade{m dr}\saccade{es-sed w}\saccade{ell y}\saccade{es-t}\saccade{er-d}}
\Comment[r]{Exit\\saccade}{\Esaccade{ay}}

\labelsaccade{C}
\Comment[l]{Entry\\saccade}{\Ssaccade{Ji}}
\Comment{Minisaccades (with bad estim.)}
{\saccade{m dr}\saccade{es-ses w}\saccade{ell y}\saccade{es-t}
\stackunder[2\baselineskip]{\dashsaccade{er-d}\nosaccade{ay}}{%
  \llap{\rotatebox{50}{$\leftarrow$}}\small\itshape\Longunderstack[l]{\rule{9ex}{2pt}\kern1ex\\Conflict\\detected}}}

\labelsaccade{D}
\noSsaccade{Jim dr}
\saccade{es-sed w}\saccade{ell y}\saccade{es-t}\saccade{er-d}
\Comment[r]{Exit\\saccade}{\Esaccade{ay}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

One idea towards a solution, but lots of work could be done to make the macros/styles more flexible and reusable:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  minisaccade/.style={inner xsep=0pt},
  labelsaccade/.style={font=\itshape\small, align=left, inner xsep=0pt},
  connectsaccade/.style={},
}
\newcommand{\placeseq}[3]{%
  \node (#2) at (#1) {#2\strut};
  \path (#2.south east) +(5.5em,0) coordinate (#2init);
  \foreach \elem[remember=\elem as \lastelem (initially init)] in {#3} {%
    \node[minisaccade,anchor=south west] at (#2\lastelem.south east) 
      (#2\elem) {\strut\elem};
  }
}
\newcommand{\entryto}[3][]{%
  \draw[#1] (#2#3.north) to[out=90,in=0] +(-1em,0.75em) -- +(-5em,0)
    node[labelsaccade,above,anchor=south west] {Entry\\saccade}%
}
\newcommand{\exitfrom}[3][]{%
  \draw[#1] (#2#3.north) to[out=90,in=180] +(1em,0.75em) -- +(5em,0)
    node[labelsaccade,above,anchor=south east] {Exit\\saccade}%
}
\newcommand{\connect}[4][]{%
  \draw[connectsaccade,#1] (#2#3.north) 
    to[out=90,in=180] ($(#2#3.north)!0.5!(#2#4.north)+(0,0.75em)$) 
    to[out=0,in=90] (#2#4.north)
}
\newcommand{\labelover}[5][]{%
  \node[labelsaccade,anchor=south,#1] 
    at ($(#2#3.north west)!0.5!(#2#4.north east)+(0,0.75em)$) {#5}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % Sequence A
  \placeseq{0,0}{A}{Jim, ,dres,--,seX, ,well, ,yes,--,ter,--,day}
  \connect{A}{Jim}{dres};
  \connect{A}{dres}{seX};
  \connect{A}{seX}{well};
  \connect{A}{well}{yes};
  \connect{A}{yes}{ter};
  \connect{A}{ter}{day};
  \entryto {A}{Jim};
  \exitfrom {A}{day};
  \labelover{A}{Jim}{day}{Minisaccades (without estim.)};
 % Sequence B
  \placeseq{0,-2}{B}{Jim, ,dres,--,sed, ,well, ,yes,--,ter,--,day}
  \connect{B}{Jim}{dres};
  \connect{B}{dres}{well};
  \connect{B}{well}{yes};
  \connect{B}{yes}{ter};
  \connect{B}{ter}{day};
  \entryto {B}{Jim};
  \exitfrom {B}{day};
  \labelover{B}{Jim}{day}{Minisaccades (without correct estim.)};
 % Sequence C
  \placeseq{0,-4}{C}{Jim, ,dres,--,ses, ,well, ,yes,--,ter,--,day}
  \connect{C}{Jim}{dres};
  \connect{C}{dres}{well};
  \connect{C}{well}{yes};
  \connect{C}{yes}{ter};
  \connect[dashed]{C}{ter}{day};
  \entryto {C}{Jim};
  \labelover{C}{Jim}{day}{Minisaccades (with bad estim.)};
 % Sequence D
  \placeseq{0,-7}{D}{Jim, ,dres,--,sed, ,well, ,yes,--,ter,--,day}
  \connect{D}{dres}{sed};
  \connect{D}{sed}{well};
  \connect{D}{well}{yes};
  \connect{D}{yes}{ter};
  \connect{D}{ter}{day};
  \exitfrom {D}{day};
  \draw[-latex,shorten >=5pt] (Cter) to[out=-90,in=90] 
    node[labelsaccade,pos=0.25,below right] {Conflict\\detected} (Ddres);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) nice! But will not work if you have two times the same syllable on the same line. For example if in the line "A" you have two "dres" the node of the second "dres" will overwrite the name `(Adres)`. Probably what you mean by "lots of work could be done ..." ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect, but basically just demonstrates the parsing of the text, so one can say...

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\saccadetext{Jim dres-ses him-self to-day and yes-ter-day I think}

\draw [dashed] (self.north)  to [saccade]         (to.north);
\draw [red]    (day-1.south) to [saccade=-0.5cm] (day-2.south);

\foreach \j [evaluate={\i=int(\j-1);}] in {2,...,5,7,8,...,13}
   \draw (syllable-\i.north) to [saccade] (syllable-\j.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

...to produce:

[image]

Each node is named by it's syllable name, duplicate syllables are automatically suffixed, so the above example will result in nodes named `day-1` and `day-2`. In addition each syllable can be referred to as `syllable-1`, `syllable-2` and so on.

It is very likely to fail with languages more "exciting" than English.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\makeatletter
\newcount\syllablecount

\def\parsesaccadetext#1{\syllablecount=0\relax\@parsesaccadetext#1 @stop@}
\def\@stop@{@stop@}
\def\@parsesaccadetext#1 {%
  \let\@next=\relax%
  \def\@tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\@tmp\@stop@%
  \else%
    \let\@next=\@parsesaccadetext%
    \@parsesaccadesyllable#1-@stop@-%
    \let\@next=\@parsesaccadetext%
  \fi%
  \@next%
}

\def\@parsesaccadesyllable#1-{%
  \def\@tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\@tmp\@stop@%
    \let\@next=\relax%
  \else%
    \ifx\@next\@parsesaccadesyllable%
      \dosaccadehyphen%
    \fi%
    \dosaccadesyllable{#1}%
    \let\@next=\@parsesaccadesyllable%
  \fi%
  \@next%
}

\def\getnodename#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname saccade@syllable#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\def\csname saccade@syllable#1\endcsname{1}%
    \edef\nodename{\saccadeprefix#1}%
  \else
    \ifnum\csname saccade@syllable#1\endcsname=1%
      \pgfnodealias{\saccadeprefix#1-1}{\saccadeprefix#1}%
     \fi
     \count0=\csname saccade@syllable#1\endcsname\relax%
     \advance\count0 by 1\relax%
     \expandafter\edef\csname saccade@syllable#1\endcsname{\the\count0}%
     \edef\nodename{\saccadeprefix#1-\the\count0}%
  \fi
}
\def\dosaccadesyllable#1{%
  \getnodename{#1}%
  \node [on chain, anchor=base west, inner xsep=.5ex, every syllable/.try] 
    (\nodename) {#1};
  \advance\syllablecount by1\relax%
  \pgfnodealias{\saccadeprefix syllable-\the\syllablecount}{\nodename}%
}
\def\dosaccadehyphen{%
  \node [on chain, anchor=base west, inner xsep=-.5ex] {-};
}

\tikzset{%
  saccade prefix/.store in=\saccadeprefix,
  saccade prefix=,
  saccade/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) .. controls ++(90:#1) and ++(90:#1) .. (\tikztotarget)
    }
  },
  saccade/.default=0.25cm,
  every syllable/.style={inner ysep=0pt, execute at begin node=\strut}
}
\newcommand\saccadetext[2][]{
    \begin{scope}[start chain=going {at=(\tikzchainprevious.base east)},#1]
      \parsesaccadetext{#2}
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\saccadetext{Jim dres-ses him-self to-day and yes-ter-day I think}

\draw [dashed] (self.north)  to [saccade]         (to.north);
\draw [red]    (day-1.south) to [saccade=-0.5cm] (day-2.south);

\foreach \j [evaluate={\i=int(\j-1);}] in {2,...,5,7,8,...,13}
   \draw (syllable-\i.north) to [saccade] (syllable-\j.north);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```